# Signing transaction for later use

Tags: bitcoind, utxo

If I have a segwit UTXO  with for example 10 BTC , can I make some raw transactions ready to get broadcasted?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Pseudonymous can I make some raw transactions ready to get broadcasted? for example if I don't want to reveal my private key ,  can I sign some raw transactions and broadcast them in the future?

Comment: Yes. There is no restriction on broadcasting a transaction hours, days or even years after they are signed. You can add a lock time to prevent them from being valid until a certain time if you choose.

Comment: @Pseudonymous What if I don't use a segwit UTXO?

Comment: Really has nothing to do with segwit either way.

Comment: @Pseudonymus If the utxo and receiver are same is the transaction hash the same?

Comment: I mean the signed transaction not the transaction hash